Slow points of diffusion processes
Let $W$ be a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion, and $X$ the solution to the SDE
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t,$$
with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ Lipschitz continuous.
Given a (deterministic) continuous path $\gamma: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R^d$, we say that $t \geq 0$ is a slow point of $\gamma$ if
$$\lim_{s \to t^+} \frac{|\gamma_t - \gamma_s|}{|t-s|^{1/2}} = 0.$$
Question: Let $S$ denote the (random) set of slow points of $X$. Is it true that
$$S = \{t \geq 0\, | \, \sigma(X_t) = 0\}$$
almost surely?

Typically slow point means that the limit is finite but then the question is less interesting (see eg https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00532967). Just a comment for future readers.

@user479223 Thanks for the clarifying comment. By the way, I’ve slightly modified the definition of slow point (the limit is taken only from the right now). I think this version should be easier to analyze.

can we ignore the drift term since it is Lipschitz continuous? And so we study the time changed BM $dX_t=\sigma(X_t)dW_t=B_{A_{t}}$ (Karatzas-Shreve time change). Then I suppose that we end up studying the regularity of $A_{t}$

@ThomasKojar Yes, the drift term by virtue of being Lipschitz will only contribute a term of order $|t-s|$ which is negligible compared to $|t - s|^{1/2}$.
